# Meteor - Publish array - but how do i Subscribe?

Tags: javascript, meteor

I have this Publish on the server

```
Meteor.publish('events', function(){
    var currentUserId = this.userId;
    var events_private = Events.find({ UserId: currentUserId });
    var events_internal = Events.find({ 'Option.option_vis' : "internal"});
    var events_public = Events.find({ 'Option.option_vis' : "public"});
    if (events_UsersOwn){
      return eventsForUser = [
        events_private//
        events_UsersOwn,
        events_public
      ]
    }
    return this.ready();
});
```

On the client I would like to subscribe. But how do I get in touch with the behind data? I have tried following:

```
Meteor.subscribe('events.events_private');
```

And ind the method

```
Template.eventTemplate.helpers({
    returnUsersEvents: function(){
        console.log(Events.find({}).fetch());
    }
});
```

I am doing it wrong / understanding it wrong, but I think that i'm close. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When returning an array of cursors from a publish function, each cursor must be from a different collection. You have 3 cursors from the Events collection. This is not supported.

You need to create 3 separate publications.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense.